# What's the correct way to encode CR-LF line breaks in text/xml values?

Tags: xml, xml-serialization

As opposed to application/xml files which could do anything, or normalizedString values which convert all whitespace sequences to a single space character, I'm asking here specifically in the context of text/xml files with string values. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I'm only using ASCII characters with a UTF8 encoded file.

Given the following two-line text string I wish to represent in XML:

```
Hello
World!
```

Which is the following bytes in memory:

```
0000: 48 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 57 6f 72 6c 64 21 Hello..World!
```

According to RFC 2046, any text/* MIME type MUST (not should) represent a line break using Carriage Return followed by Linefeed character sequence. In that light, the following XML fragment should be right:

```
<tag>Hello
World!</tag>
```

or

```
0000: 3c 74 61 67 3c 48 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 57 6f 72 6c <tag>Hello..Worl
0010: 64 21 3c 2f 74 61 67 3c                         d!</tag>
```

But I regularly see files like the following:

```
<tag><![CDATA[Hello
World!]]></tag>
```

Or, even stranger:

```
<tag>Hello&xD;
World!</tag>
```

Where the &0xD; sequence is followed by a single Linefeed character:

```
0000: 3c 74 61 67 3c 48 65 6c 6c 6f 26 78 44 3b 0a 57 <tag>Hello&xD;.W
0010: 6f 72 6c 64 21 3c 2f 74 61 67 3c                orld!</tag>
```

What am I missing here? What's the correct way to represent multiple lines of text in an XML string value so that it can come out the other end unmolested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing NUnit tests in Mono and JUnit tests in Java, the answer would appear to be to use either <tag>Hello&#13;\nWorld!</tag> or <tag>Hello&#xd;\nWorld!</tag> as below...

Foo.cs:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlStringTests
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string greeting;

        public static Foo DeserializeFromXmlString (string xml)
        {
            Foo result;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (xml);
                memoryStream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                memoryStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof(Foo));
                result = (Foo)xs.Deserialize (memoryStream);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

XmlStringTests.cs:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace XmlStringTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class XmlStringTests
    {
        const string expected = "Hello\u000d\u000aWorld!";

        [Test(Description="Fails")]
        public void Cdata ()
        {
            const string test = "<Foo><greeting><![CDATA[Hello\u000d\u000aWorld!]]></greeting></Foo>";
            Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
            Assert.AreEqual (expected, bar.greeting);
        }

        [Test(Description="Fails")]
        public void CdataWithHash13 ()
        {
            const string test = "<Foo><greeting><![CDATA[Hello&#13;\u000aWorld!]]></greeting></Foo>";
            Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
            Assert.AreEqual (expected, bar.greeting);
        }

        [Test(Description="Fails")]
        public void CdataWithHashxD ()
        {
            const string test = "<Foo><greeting><![CDATA[Hello&#xd;\u000aWorld!]]></greeting></Foo>";
            Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
            Assert.AreEqual (expected, bar.greeting);
        }

        [Test(Description="Fails")]
        public void Simple ()
        {
            const string test = "<Foo><greeting>Hello\u000d\u000aWorld!</greeting></Foo>";
            Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
            Assert.AreEqual (expected, bar.greeting);
        }

        [Test(Description="Passes")]
        public void SimpleWithHash13 ()
        {
            const string test = "<Foo><greeting>Hello&#13;\u000aWorld!</greeting></Foo>";
            Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
            Assert.AreEqual (expected, bar.greeting);
        }

        [Test(Description="Passes")]
        public void SimpleWithHashxD ()
        {
            const string test = "<Foo><greeting>Hello&#xd;\u000aWorld!</greeting></Foo>";
            Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
            Assert.AreEqual (expected, bar.greeting);
        }
    }
}
```

Foo.java:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "greeting" })
public class Foo {
    public String greeting;

    public static Foo DeserializeFromXmlString(String xml) {
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
            return foo;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

XmlStringTests.java:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class XmlStringTests {
    String expected = "Hello\r\nWorld!";

    @Test //Fails
    public void testCdata ()
    {
        String test = "<Foo><greeting><![CDATA[Hello\r\nWorld!]]></greeting></Foo>";
        Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
        assertEquals (expected, bar.greeting);
    }

    @Test //Fails
    public void testCdataWithHash13 ()
    {
        String test = "<Foo><greeting><![CDATA[Hello&#13;\nWorld!]]></greeting></Foo>";
        Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
        assertEquals (expected, bar.greeting);
    }

    @Test //Fails
    public void testCdataWithHashxD ()
    {
        String test = "<Foo><greeting><![CDATA[Hello&#xd;\nWorld!]]></greeting></Foo>";
        Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
        assertEquals (expected, bar.greeting);
    }

    @Test //Fails
    public void testSimple ()
    {
        String test = "<Foo><greeting>Hello\r\nWorld!</greeting></Foo>";
        Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
        assertEquals (expected, bar.greeting);
    }

    @Test //Passes
    public void testSimpleWithHash13 ()
    {
        String test = "<Foo><greeting>Hello&#13;\nWorld!</greeting></Foo>";
        Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
        assertEquals (expected, bar.greeting);
    }

    @Test //Passes
    public void testSimpleWithHashxD ()
    {
        String test = "<Foo><greeting>Hello&#xd;\nWorld!</greeting></Foo>";
        Foo bar = Foo.DeserializeFromXmlString (test);
        assertEquals (expected, bar.greeting);
    }
}
```

I hope this saves some people some time.

Answer (score 4):

CR (&x0D;), LF (&x0A;), CRLF, or a few other combinations are all valid.  As noted in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml11-20040204/#sec-line-ends), all of these are translated to a single &x0A; character.

Comment: According to the same spec, CR (#d) is a valid Char inside CDATA blocks and so should not be transformed. I would define getting an LF back from CR LF input as being molested. Is there a way to properly encode the XML to get the CR LF back out at the receiving end, or is XML just broken and undeserving of the text/xml MIME type?

Comment: When reading the spec, I interpret it as this: if any of the following raw code point sequences is found in the input, replace it with `0xd 0xa`: `0xd 0x85`, `0x85`, `0x2028`, `0xd «anything other than 0xa or 0x85»`. Since this replacement happens “before parsing” (see your reference), any literal character entity (i.e., `<tag>&#xd</tag>`) should be preserved. So for that example, the parsed content should be the byte sequence `0xd` instead of `0xa`. Am I reading the spec correctly? Your answer seems to suggest that this replacement might happen **after parsing** instead of before…

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found which would work for the <![CDATA elements was to do a string replace of CR with the text of a GUID before passing the XML in, then replace the GUID back to CR after retrieval.

Using a GUID rather than a fixed escape sequence means there's no chance of accidentally clashing with data that was already there.