# Carriage return in XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement, carriage-return

I want to produce an XML file where carriage return in elements are represented by the following sequence `&#13;` but I'm unable get:

```
<elem>Hello&#13;world!</elem>
```

If I do the following:

```
var elem = new XElement("elem", "Hello\nworld!");
```

It produces:

```
<elem>Hello
world!</elem>
```

If I do the following:

```
var elem = new XElement("elem", "Hello&#13;world!");
```

It produces:

```
<elem>Hello&amp;#13;world!</elem>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to encode CR-LF line breaks in text/xml values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016004/whats-the-correct-way-to-encode-cr-lf-line-breaks-in-text-xml-values)

Comment: @JustinRusso There was a mistake in my formatting but as you can see `&#13;` produces `&amp;#13;`

Comment: @paqogomez It doesn't provide interesting information. In my case the expected string is `Hello&#13;world`

Comment: `var elem = new XElement("elem", "Hello&#13;world!");
            Console.WriteLine(elem.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(elem);` gives me `Hello&#13;world!<elem>Hello&amp;#13;world!</elem>
` which means that the value of elem is stored as you asked, isn't it ?

Comment: In fact I want it in the file, but I find a way of using the XDocument.ToString() method

Comment: Since my answer is the actual answer to your question, can you mark it as the "Answer?"  Thanks.  Justin

Answer (score 1):

Okay your answer is pretty clear.  Anytime you need to write special chars into xml values, you would use CDATA.

Here's how you do it.

```
<elem><![CDATA[Hello&#13;world!]]></elem>
```

This is the fix you are looking for.

[UPDATE]
The only reason I stumbled on this answer initially, was because I was thinking about HTML.  However, if you were writing this in HTML, you would simply use a `<br />` tag.